# Including images in phonegap with xcode; finding "Targets"?

Tags: xcode, cordova

I'm trying to include a .png on a page in a phonegap app in xcode. I included it properly in resources, including the "Copy items..." checkbox and all that, but I'm still getting a little error box on the page instead of an image.

I read [this](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494763/Building%20A%20Self-Contained%20Application%20%28iPhone%29) page for help, and the last part of the page, under "Troubleshooting" at the bottom, shows a solution to my problem. However, I cannot find the targets folder in XCode. It simply isn't there. In the image near the middle of that tutorial you can see that the Targets folder is below the frameworks folder, along with a bunch of other stuff like "Executables" and "Errors and Warnings", but for me there's nothing after frameworks except the Products folder. All those things you can see in the picture simply aren't there. I'm using XCode version 4.2. Where can I find the targets folder?

Answer (score -1):

So probably the Xcode you are using is an upgraded version. The Xcode 4.2 Target's location is changed and you can refer [this image](https://img.skitch.com/20111208-diucey1rnscaqhe4qnyffbj462.png) (picked randomly from google images), so see this and you will know where to find the targets settings.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that's a different "Targets", as it has none of the same things beneath it. The keyword 'Target' is used in many places.

Comment: The second yellow arrow below in the left is the target Aerovistae looking for. that is exactly what is required.

Comment: Hmm. If you look at the picture in his link, there are some folders beneath the 'Targets' he was referring to, including a "Copy Bundle Resources" folder, which is what's needed for this. I don't see that stuff in the picture you showed, but I could be mistaken. Can you point out how to find it from there?

Comment: the link which he has given is a older version of xcode 3.2.x and the xcode what he using is xcode 4.2.x. Sorry Apple has changed their UI big time here.